# If a partition $(A_i)_{i\in I}$ satisfies $P(A_i)>0$ then $I$ is at most countable

Tags: general-topology, probability-theory, measure-theory

I want to show that if a partition $(A_i)_{i\in I}$ satisfies $P(A_i)>0$ for all $i$ then $I$ is at most countable to avoid problems in a larger proof. I know this is true, however, I'm finding it difficult to prove/argue this seemingly obvious statement.

I tried arguing using covers of the compact $[0,1]$, which the sum $\sum_i P(A_i)$ must "fill", but that approach already assumed that the partition was finite.

Am I missing some bit of topology? Or is there another way entirely?

Comment: Hint: If $I$ isn't countable, then $\{A_i : P(A_i) > 1/n\}$ must be at least countably infinite for at least one $n$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No topology is involved here. I suppose your $P$ is a probability measure (or at least a finite measure).

Consider $I_j=\{i: P(A_i) >\frac 1j\}$ where $j$ is a positive inrteger. If there are $n$ elements in this set, say $i_1,i_2,..,i_n$ then $P(\Omega) \geq P(\bigcup_{1\leq k \leq n} A_{i_k}) = \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} P(A_{i_k})>\frac n j $. This proves that there are at most finitely  many points in this set. Now take union over all $j$ and you will get the proof.  ($I=\bigcup_j I_j$).